# How to send command from my android app to android terminal emulator?

Tags: android

I want to send command from my Android Application to android terminal emulator.

Following is my code.

```
public void onClick(View p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("*/*");
    i.setPackage("jackpal.androidterm");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"date");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For executing a shell command you don't need Terminal Emulator App. Android is based on the Linux kernel so you can directly execute shell commands.

Try this code,

```
// Command to execute
String command = "date";
ShellExecuter exe = new ShellExecuter();
String outp = exe.Executer(command);
out.setText(outp);
Log.d("Output", outp);
```